# Python Decorator Code Runs Before Original Function Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

```
def raw_list(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(args, producer_data):
        print producer_data[2]
        tenant, token, url = producer_data
        body, status_code = do_request(url, token)
        return function(args, producer_data)
    return wrapper

@raw_list
def member_list(args, producer_data):
    # in argparse, consumer or producer data can be used because
    # consumer is aliased to producer.
    uuid = args['uuid']
    producer_data[2] = producer_data[2] + "/" + uuid + "/members"
```

I have several functions that take a URL, mutate it, and make an API call with the URL. For this reason, I made a wrapper function the for the API call part. So, each function only needs to mutate the URL and be decorated with the wrapper function.

But the issue I am having is that the mutated URL code `producer_data[2] = producer_data[2] + "/" + uuid + "/members"` seems to be running after the function decorator code runs, and not before. Because of this, the original URL is being used instead of the mutated URL.

How can I fix this logic flow and make it to where the API call is made with the mutated URL?

Comment: Of course it's running afterwards, you call it afterwards in the decorator!

Comment: Why do you store `body` and `status_code`, only to immediately throw them away? Is it just a reminder of what `do_request` returns?

Comment: some functions may use them later

Answer (score 5):

If you want the decorated function to be called before the rest of the wrapper's code, call it before the rest of the wrapper's code:

```
def raw_list(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(args, producer_data):
        # Call it here!
        retval = function(args, producer_data)
        print producer_data[2]
        tenant, token, url = producer_data
        body, status_code = do_request(url, token)
        return retval
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 3):

The method that mutates the URL is called as the last statement of you decorator which means that the URL you are passing to the `do_request` function is the original URL.
You'll want to called the decorated function first to get the API URL and then actually call the `do_request`.

Answer (score 2):

It will run after the decorator code, because the call to the function is at the end of the wrapper. You make the request and assign to `body` and `status_code`, (though you never do anything with those values), then call `member_list`. It modifies `producer_data`, but by then it is too late.

Answer (score 1):

```
@xxx
def yyy(): pass
```

is the same as

```
def yyy(): pass
yyy = xxx(yyy)
```

Maybe this helps.